# MS Access ALTER TABLE

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to add a column to an existing table. here is what I have.

```
ALTER TABLE [test] ADD COLUMN test_column int();
```

I am getting this error. "Syntax error in ALTER TABLE statement"

Comment: Why are you implementing code to alter table as opposed to just opening table in design view?

Comment: Im trying to find an automated way to do it

Comment: Yes, I understand you want to automate but why? I am suspicious of code that alters db design. If this is a frequent routine, then the db structure might not be optimally normalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parentheses `()`

```
ALTER TABLE [test] ADD COLUMN test_column int;
```

Parentheses are used for string datatypes with variable lengths or datatypes with precision and scale. `int` is a set length.

Comment: would there be a way to get the column to be added to the front? I added ALTER TABLE [test] ADD COLUMN test_column int FIRST; but it just added it to the end

Comment: @J.Doe None that I know of, the usual method is to drop and recreate the table if you have to do it thru a script.

Comment: But do note: column ordering is more an aesthetic issue than anything else. Simply specify your ordering in `SELECT` clause.